# Name pronunciation

Tags: pronunciation, names

Are the following two words (last name "translated" to Japanese for context) pronounced the same?

- ミイヨ In this case the second syllable is the katakana equivalent of I.
- ミーヨ In this case it is just a long vowel mark which is after ミ (Mi).

So, will they sound the same?

**EDIT**: Question changed to not to make it about a translation.

Comment: How is this not a translation/transcription request? We don't service these on the site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it’s pronounced like Spanish, I would suggest either one of ミーヨ, ミージョ, and ミーリョ depending on how you want the double-L part to be rendered.

If it’s pronounced the French way with stress on the last syllable, Japanese speakers might hear it as ミヨ or even ミヨー rather than ミーヨ.

ミイヨ is cute, though.

Comment: I really like your answer. What do you exactly mean by "cute"? I wonder also if in the Italian case (pronunciated Mil·lo if it was written in Catalan) would be even possible to be pronunciated by Japanese since it really puts the effort on the L part.

Comment: @maximusboscus - I can’t explain why but ミイヨ looks cute. That’s not how a long sound is usually written. The Italian (or Catalan) pronunciation with a geminate L would be ミッロ. It is hard to pronounce.

Answer (score -2):

ミロ = Millo

If you write ミイヨ or ミーヨ , it would be pronounced as "Miiyo" or "Myo".

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I think double Ls in French and Spanish *are* pronounced like y though

Comment: @Angelos, Millo in French is pronunciated as Meelo. In Spanish is pronunciated as Meeyo.